# Optimise a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, optimization

I'm quite new to javascript, but have managed to write a working xml function :)

I was hoping someone could please give me a rundown of how to optimise the function.  At present there's a different function for each state's weather, but I was hoping I could simplify this somehow.

Code is pasted here: http://pastie.org/private/ffuvwgbeenhyo07vqkkcsw

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

EDIT: ADDING CODE EXAMPLES OF BOTH XML FEEDS:

Function 1 (UV): http://pastie.org/private/jc9oxkexypn0cw5yaskiq

Function 2 (weather): http://pastie.org/private/pnckz4k4yabgvtdbsjvvrq

Comment: I am seeing quite a bit of duplication but quality wise I would say it is quite good for someone just learning the language.

Comment: A *lot* of repetition. Also, you're definitely going to bump into cross domain restrictions if you're going to actually try running that code on any website other than the site which is providing you with the information

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the functions are basically the same between cities - other than the fact they are 'different' cities & require different xml feeds.  Cross domain is luckily not a problem cause it's for a webapp, packaged for iphone - so will be working from a local dir.

Comment: Oh I should also mention, the data pulled from the xml is being inserted into div's in the html.  This is another point of difference between all the functions - the divs are all different depending on the state/xml feed

Comment: Really appreciate everyone's help below! Really really helpful!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you create an array that holds the UV element IDs, suffixes and weather station ids (*stationid*)

```
var areas = [
     {id:'sydney',suffix:'syd',stationid:'YSSY'},
     {id:'melbourne',suffix:'mel',stationid:'YMML'},
     {id:'brisbane',suffix:'bri',stationid:'YBBN'},
     {id:'perth',suffix:'per',stationid:'YPPH'},
     ...
 ]
```

and then for the **UV**

```
// FUNCTION 1 - UV
function getUV() {

    // BEGIN AUSTRALIAN UV FUNCTION

    $.get('http://www.arpansa.gov.au/uvindex/realtime/xml/uvvalues.xml', function(d) {

        //SYDNEY UV
             $(areas).each(function(){
            var area = this;
        $(d).find('location#'+area.name).each(function(){

            var $location = $(this); 
            var uvindex = $location.find('index').text();

            var areauv = areauv += '<span>' + uvindex + '</span>' ;
            $('#uv-'+area.suffix).empty().append($(areauv)); // empty div first

            if (uvindex <= 2.0) {
                $('#risk-'+area.suffix).empty().append('Low');
                $('#curcon-'+area.suffix).empty().append('You can safely stay outdoors and use an SPF 15 moisturiser.');
            } else if (uvindex <= 5.0) {
                $('#risk-'+area.suffix).empty().append('Moderate');
                $('#curcon-'+area.suffix).empty().append('Wear protective clothing outdoors and use an SPF 15 or SPF 30 moisturiser.');
            } else if (uvindex <= 7.0) {
                $('#risk-'+area.suffix).empty().append('High');
                $('#curcon-'+area.suffix).empty().append('Wear protective clothing, limit your time outdoors and use an SPF 30 moisturiser.');
            } else if (uvindex <= 10.0) {
                $('#risk-'+area.suffix).empty().append('Very High');
                $('#curcon-'+area.suffix).empty().append('Use caution, limit exposure to the sun and use an SPF 30 moisturiser.');
            } else if (uvindex <= 20.0) {
                $('#risk-'+area.suffix).empty().append('Extreme');
                $('#curcon-'+area.suffix).empty().append('Use extreme caution, avoid exposure to the sun and use an SPF 30 moisturiser.');
            } else {
                $('#risk-'+area.suffix).empty().append('Unavailable');
                $('#curcon-'+area.suffix).empty().append('Information is currently unavailable.');
            }

        });
            });

        // END OF AUSTRALIAN UV FUNCTION

    });
}
```

and for the **weather**

```
function getWeather() {

        // BEGIN AUSTRALIA and NEW ZEALAND WEATHER FUNCTION
            $(areas).each(function(){
                var area = this;
        $.get('http://api.wxbug.net/getLiveCompactWeatherRSS.aspx?ACode=XXXPRIVATEXXX&stationid='+area.stationid+'&unittype=1&outputtype=1', function(d){
        $(d).find('weather').each(function(){

            var $weatherinfo = $(this); 
            var degrees = $weatherinfo.find('temp').text().replace(/\.0$/i, "");
            var conditions = $weatherinfo.find('current-condition').text();
            var icon = $weatherinfo.find('current-condition').attr('icon').replace(/\.gif$/i, ".png").split('http://deskwx.weatherbug.com/')[1];

            var temperature = temperature += '<span>' + degrees + '</span>' ;   
            $('#temp-'+area.suffix).empty().append($(temperature));

            var winformation = winformation += '<span>' + conditions + '</span>' ;
            $('#info-'+area.suffix).empty().append($(winformation));

            var wicon = wicon += '<img src="' + icon + '" alt="Weather Unavailable" />' ;
            $('#icon-'+area.suffix).empty().append($(wicon));

        });
        });
            });
}
```

Comment: All worked great, just had to change +area.name to +area.id in the UV function to make it work!

Answer (score 7):

```
$(d).find('location#sydney')
```

Is questionable. `#sydney` means an element with an attribute valued `sydney` that has the schema type `ID`. In HTML, the `id="..."` attribute has schema type `ID` thanks to the DOCTYPE. But this XML file has no DOCTYPE and hence its `id="..."` attributes don't have schema type `ID`. Consequently `getElementById('sydney')` won't work, and `#sydney` as a selector shouldn't work.

It works in practice because when you use `find()` jQuery falls back to its own ‘Sizzle’ JavaScript selector matcher, which simply looks for `id="..."` attributes as if it were HTML. But Sizzle is slow and you shouldn't rely on this implementation detail. Using the explicit attribute selector `location[id=sydney]` is better for an XML document.

```
var sydneyuv = sydneyuv += '<span>' + uvindex + '</span>' ;
```

You've got a superfluous assignment here. You use the augmented assignment `+=` to add something to `sydneyuv`, and then you assign the result to `sydneyuv` again.

Also, it's generally best not to stitch together strings of HTML from input values. What if `uvindex` had HTML-special characters in? (It probably won't, but there's nothing stopping the site you're scraping from including them.) Without HTML-escaping you'd have HTML-injection and potentially XSS security holes. Always use DOM-style methods, like `text()` and `attr()` in jQuery, or the creation shortcut: `var $sydneyuv= $('<span/>', {text: uvindex});`, in preference to string-slinging.

> I was hoping I could simplify this somehow.

Sure. Make it data-driven:

```
var towns= ['sydney', 'melbourne', 'brisbane', 'perth', 'adelaide', 'darwin'];
var uvlevels= [
    {uvlevel: 2,    risk: 'Low',         curcon: 'You can safely stay outdoors and use an SPF 15 moisturiser.'},
    {uvlevel: 5,    risk: 'Moderate',    curcon: 'Wear protective clothing outdoors and use an SPF 15 or SPF 30 moisturiser.'},
    {uvlevel: 7,    risk: 'High',        curcon: 'Wear protective clothing, limit your time outdoors and use an SPF 30 moisturiser.'},
    {uvlevel: 10,   risk: 'Very high',   curcon: 'Use caution, limit exposure to the sun and use an SPF 30 moisturiser.'},
    {uvlevel: 20,   risk: 'Extreme',     curcon: 'Use extreme caution, avoid exposure to the sun and use an SPF 30 moisturiser.'},
    {uvlevel: null, risk: 'Unavailable', curcon: 'Information is currently unavailable.'}
];
```

Now you can replace all those separate statements with one loop:

```
$.each(towns, function() {
    var $location= $(d).find('location[id='+this+']');
    var uv= $location.find('index').text();
    var shorttown= this.slice(0, 3);
    $('#uv-'+shortttown).empty().append($('<span/>', {text: uv}));
    $.each(uvlevels, function() {
        if (this.uvlevel===null || uv<=this.uvlevel) {
            $('#risk-'+shorttown).text(this.risk);
            $('#curcon-'+shorttown).text(this.curcon);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

and presumably similar for whatever the weather one's doing.

(I'd use the full town ID in the HTML document IDs, so you don't need the `shorttown` hack.)

Comment: My goal was to leave a bit of work for the OP to do so they learn something! *(Who am I kidding I didn't want to type all that out...)*

Comment: heh. There's still the weather to do, I got bored :-)

Comment: Incredibly helpful to see the reworked code & compare to my own!  Don't worry, im learning my ass off here! :)

Comment: Just on your intro paragraph too, i've added the xml feeds to the original question.

Comment: Ahh, that sizzle tidbit is great advice!  Thanks!!

Comment: The Weather one is a bit different as it uses a different XML feed for every state (unlike UV which uses a single feed).  Is there a best practice you might suggest for this?

Comment: There's no particular problem with that, you can still do the `$.get()` with inline `function() {}` callback all inside a `$.each()` loop.

Answer (score 2):

A simplified version would look something like this:

```
var cities = ['sydney', 'melbourne', 'brisbane', 'perth', 'adelaide', 'darwin'], 
    risks = {
        2: {
            risk: 'Low', 
            curcon: 'You can safely stay outdoors and use an SPF 15 moisturiser.'
        }
        5: {
            risk: 'Moderate', 
            curcon: 'Wear protective clothing outdoors and use an SPF 15 or SPF 30 moisturiser.'
        }
        7: {
            risk: 'High', 
            curcon: 'Use caution, limit exposure to the sun and use an SPF 30 moisturiser.'
        }
        10: {
            risk: 'Very High', 
            curcon: 'Use caution, limit exposure to the sun and use an SPF 30 moisturiser.'
        }
        20: {
            risk: 'Extreme', 
            curcon: 'Use extreme caution, avoid exposure to the sun and use an SPF 30 moisturiser.'
        }
    };

for(var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
    var shortCityName = cities[i].substring(0, 3);

    $(d).find('location#sydney').each(function(){
        var $location = $(this); 
        var uvindex = parseInt($location.find('index').text(), 10);

        $('#uv-' + shortCityName).html('<span>' + uvindex + '</span>');

        for(var i in risks){
            if(uvindex < risks[i]){
                $('#risk-' + shortCityName).html(risks[i].risk);
                $('#curcon-' + shortCityName).html(risks[i].curcon);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Using an object to store the messages, then an array to store the names of the cities. Also, instead of using this:

```
var wicon = wicon += '<img src="' + icon + '" alt="Weather Unavailable" />' ;
```

You can use this instead:

```
var wicon = $('<img /').attr({
    src: icon, 
    alt: 'Weather Unavailable'
});
```

And finally, requesting XML information cross-domain will cause problems. See if the API provides the information in JSONP format instead. JSON is also (slightly) easier to work with using JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm, good point about the cross-origin AJAX. I don't know how the script is ‘working’ at the moment, given that: it shouldn't be.

Comment: Heya, all working currently cause it's being loaded from a local source (webapp packaged as iphone app). :)

Comment: But yeah you're right... I do plan to release a webapp version, so when it's hosted, I guess that issue will become more apparent.

Comment: @Nalga That would explain a lot :) But still, a JSON source would certainly make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you enough to remove a whole bunch of duplication.

```
var lte2 = { risk: "Low", curcon: "You can safely stay outdoors and use an SPF 15 moisturiser." },
    lte5 = { risk: "Moderate", curcon: "Wear protective clothing outdoors and use an SPF 15 or SPF 30 moisturiser." },
    lte7 = { risk: "High", curcon: "Wear protective clothing, limit your time outdoors and use an SPF 30 moisturiser." },
    uvWarningMap = {
        0: lte2,
        1: lte2,
        2: lte2,
        3: lte5,
        4: lte5,
        5: lte5,
        6: lte7,
        7: lte7
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generalize the function so that each method can support any city. Right now I don't see anything different between what you're doing for Brisbane and Melbourne, for example. The warnings are the same.